# Devise: User exists when using apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartment-gem

I have setup the Apartment gem, and have a user table in each tenant, but if I tries to create a user with the same email in two different tenants, I get **"User exists"** when I tries to create the user in the second tenant.

No user data is saved to the public scheme.

What have I overlooked?

Comment: that's cause devise validation of email, have you try with `user` has many tenants ?, you just need add new tenant with email's user and you don't new create new user with same email.

Comment: But how would I get all users in tenant? The app should be like: Account (tenant) has many Users. But in some cases a User can be in more than one account. I'm looking at using a table to log which account a user is connected to and putting it in the persistent_schemas array. Is this the way? I'm new to multi-tenancy btw ;)